# Is there any difference to access SQL Server and SQL Server instance from an Application server that is in DMZ

Tags: sql-server, dmz

I am new to workflow stake and don't have good knowledge in networking.
Can someone please tell me if I have an application server in DMZ which connects to SQL server instance which is not in DMZ, Is there any difference if i connect to SQL server or SQL Server instance. I am able to make connection to the SQL Server but once i try to try the instance it won't find the instance.
I.e. Can connect to sqlservername but not to sqlservername\instanename the error i am getting is the SQL Server instance can't be found. the instance is setup to allow remote connection. Hope my question make sense.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't connect to named instance? - as minimum you need to enable remote connections to this server from `SSMS->Server->Properties->Connections` or you can read, for example, [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165718(v=sql.105).aspx) article for more information how to do that. And... be sure that Sql Server Browser service is started and feels good, because it's responsible for managing connections to named instances.

[image]

2. The main issue with DMZ in my experience is dealing with authentication. Domain users usually can't access DMZ so, services such as Analysis Services (known as Cubes) for example, which allow only windows authentication, will be not accessible from the application server without extra efforts, establishing for example, kerberos auth.

Comment: Hi Andrey, thanks for your help. It was the service. Cheers